# Set names to attributes when creating JSON with row_to_json

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to rename default `f1, f2, f3...` names when using `row_to_json` function for only some columns?

I can do

`row_to_json(customers)`

returning

`{"id_customer":2,"first_name":"bla","last_name":"second_bla"}`

But if I want only names without `id_customer`, I have to use

`row_to_json(row(first_name, last_name))`

and then I get

`{"f1":"bla","f2":"second_bla"}`

And I would like to get this result with either default column names or my own. I know I can create my own composite type and use

`row_to_json(row(first_name, last_name))::my_custom_type`

but isn't it possible to do it right in the query without creating that type?

Comment: Also, see: [reference 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137237/postgres-nested-json-array-using-row-to-json) and [reference 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227142/postgresql-9-2-row-to-json-with-nested-joins) for similar

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The query

```
select 
   c.id,
   (select row_to_json(_) from (select c.first_name, c.last_name) as _) as first_last,
   c.age
from
   customers as c
```

will do what you want without any performance impact (and is not too verbose):

```
  id  |   first_last                                |   age
------+---------------------------------------------+---------
  1   | {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smit"} |   34
```

Answer (score 20):

A common table expression allows you to specify aliases explicitly, not only for the CTE but for its columns.

```
WITH data(col1,col2,cola,colb) AS (
  VALUES (1,2,'fred','bob')
)
SELECT row_to_json(data) FROM data;
```

This is different to @dezso's example in that it doesn't use `col AS alias` for each col in a `SELECT` list; it aliases the column names in the CTE table alias.

I've used a `VALUES` expression as a subquery but you can use a `SELECT` whatever you like; the point is that whatever column-aliases are provided or assumed in the subquery can be overridden in the CTE definition by specifying a column-name-list.

You can do the same thing in a subquery, again instead of using `AS alias`:

```
SELECT row_to_json(data) 
FROM (VALUES (1,2,'fred','bob')) data(col1,col2,cola,colb);
```

This doesn't work with a `ROW` expression directly; you can only cast a `ROW` to a concrete type, you cannot alias it.

```
regress=> SELECT ROW(1,2,'fred','bob') AS x(a,b,c,d);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: SELECT ROW(1,2,'fred','bob') AS x(a,b,c,d);
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `json_build_object`.

```
SELECT 
  json_build_object('id', data.customer_id, 'first_name', data.first_name, 'last_name', data.last_name) as your_json
FROM data;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH r AS (
  SELECT 'bla' AS name1, 'otherbla' AS name2
)
SELECT row_to_json(r.*)
FROM r
;
```

(Of course, the same can be achieved with

```
SELECT row_to_json(r.*)
FROM (SELECT 'bla' AS name1, 'otherbla' AS name2) r
;
```

but I found the former more readable.)

In the `WITH` part you can construct rows of any structure on the fly.

Comment: To concatenate non-jsonb with jsonb :: SELECT row_to_json(r.*) FROM (SELECT c1,c2 ::jsonb FROM us_ca_monterey_aoc.test) as r

Answer (score -2):

As simple as below:

```
(select row_to_json(row) from (select 'rkp' as "xyz","Title","Name","Code","Description" from Table) row )
```

Comment: How is this different to existing answers? You can edit the answer to explain.

Comment: @michael-green In existing answers, they have suggested using CTE (common table expression) whereas I have proposed my way directly to achieve without CTE.

Comment: Well .. yes, you did. Given the question is about constructing JSON of a certain structure I don't think moving a subquery from one construction to another is a substantive change. But fair enough.